# Trying Linear Search in java but it seems loop is not iterating

Tags: java, linear-search

I am trying to use Linear Search using java to find the name in the 2d array and print the details related to it, but the code is directly going to last loop without searching

the code is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Source {

String customerDetails[][]=new String[5][3];
Source()
{
customerDetails[0][0]="1001";
customerDetails[0][1]="Raj";
customerDetails[0][2]="Chennai";

customerDetails[1][0]="1008";
customerDetails[1][1]="Akshay";
customerDetails[1][0]="Pune";

customerDetails[2][0]="1002";
customerDetails[2][1]="Simrath";
customerDetails[2][2]="Amristar";

customerDetails[3][0]="1204";
customerDetails[3][1]="Gaurav";
customerDetails[3][2]="Delhi";

customerDetails[4][0]="1005";
customerDetails[4][1]="Ganesh";
customerDetails[4][2]="Chennai";

}

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    
    Source nc = new Source();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String key = sc.nextLine();
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            
            if(nc.customerDetails[i][j].equals(key)){
                found = true;
                System.out.println(nc.customerDetails[i][0] + '\n' + nc.customerDetails[i][1] + '\n' + nc.customerDetails[i][2]);
                break;
                
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            System.out.println("No Record Found");
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

i want to find Gaurav in the array and print
1204
Gaurav
Delhi

Comment: `customerDetails[1][0]="Pune";` should have `[1][2]`.

Comment: The `if(!found)` statement should be outside of the loops. Right now, it is inside of the outer loop, and the `break` terminates the loop after the first iteration, since the content was not found in the first iteration.

Comment: If your goal is to find by name, then why are you comparing to every element in the array? The name field is on second column (index of 1), you could iterate all the rows and match the value in that column. Having said that, I hope this is just an academic exercise. In real world, you should be using a pojo to keep this data and use a data structure other than two dimensional arrays. You could use many other data structures over 2-D array here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class test
{

    String customerDetails[][] = new String[5][3];

    test()
    {
        customerDetails[0][0] = "1001";
        customerDetails[0][1] = "Raj";
        customerDetails[0][2] = "Chennai";

        customerDetails[1][0] = "1008";
        customerDetails[1][1] = "Akshay";
        customerDetails[1][2] = "Pune";

        customerDetails[2][0] = "1002";
        customerDetails[2][1] = "Simrath";
        customerDetails[2][2] = "Amristar";

        customerDetails[3][0] = "1204";
        customerDetails[3][1] = "Gaurav";
        customerDetails[3][2] = "Delhi";

        customerDetails[4][0] = "1005";
        customerDetails[4][1] = "Ganesh";
        customerDetails[4][2] = "Chennai";

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {

        test nc = new test();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String key = sc.nextLine();
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {

                if (nc.customerDetails[i][j].equals(key))
                {
                    found = true;
                    System.out.println(nc.customerDetails[i][0] + '\n' + nc.customerDetails[i][1] + '\n' + nc.customerDetails[i][2]);
                    break;

                }
            }

        }
        if (!found)
        {
            System.out.println("No Record Found");
            // break;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work. `if(!found)` should be outside the loop to check all records.

Comment: It would make sense to convert class naming back to the original code's class name, because of clarity and also java naming conventions (class names should start uppercase).